# AJAX queryString mismatch in YII

Tags: ajax, url, yii, query-string

I have a YII view with an AJAX script in the page

```
        <script>
            $(".tasks-add").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('field')?>',
                    data: {
                        index: 1
                          },
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

Now this JS is making a call in the normal URL style(`http://myapp/task/field?index=1`) though I have made use of YII urlManager to optimize for the 'path' style of URLs using:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
              'urlFormat'=>'path',
              'showScriptName'=>false,
```

I am getting a 'Bad request error' because the URL requested by AJAX is the old ugly **?arg=value1 style**. Is there a way possible to make the AJAX call URL not have the query string like `?index=1` but like `http://myapp/task/field/index/1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YII way

```
<script>
        $(".tasks-add").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('field',array('index'=>1));?>'
            });
    </script>
```

OR

```
<script>
        $(".tasks-add").click(function(){
            <?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
                 'url'=>array('field','index'=>1),
                 'type'=>'get',
              ));?>
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate the URL string. jQuery ajax by default will append query string parameters when using GET and including data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. do it manually.

```
    <script>
        $(".tasks-add").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('field')?>'+'/index/1'
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: This Works! but am sure there is got to be a better way. Thanks for the quick fix